# Why do movies/TV have post credits scene?

Tags: credits

Why do some movies and TV shows have an extra scene after showing credits? Movies like The Avengers and X-men are some examples. Are post-credits scenes and end-credit scenes different?

Comment: I had always felt it was to encourage people to go through a few names in the credits and to appreciate their effort. It's just my opinion

Answer (score 6):

The post-credit scenes are used as a way to make sure you watch the entire movie, credits and all.  It also provides a break between the movie and the post-credit scenes.  Sometimes they're "stingers", sometimes they're bloopers, sometimes they're additional comedic bits.

Answer (score 2):

The scenes after the credits are usually "stingers". They were used as links or hookups to sequels. Now they are used as way to introduce characters and elements that will be present in a franchise.